# BNC cable to composite video cable conversion

Tags: cables, termination

I currently have a robotic cutter which has a BNC female connector connected to a composite video cable. I want to remove this extension cable and simply terminate the cable to a composite video connection, is this at all possible? [image]

Comment: You could probably just cut a BNC cable and tape the end off, unless the machine needs it to run. Provide a schematic of the output driver.

Comment: By "composite video" you mean RCA? Google BNC to RCA.

Comment: @laptop2d what I'm basically asking is; are the cores within each cable identical both sides assuming there will be two cores in each cable so that it's possible for me to solder a rca cable straight to the circuit.

Comment: They might have a different characteristic impedance. For RF it would be 50Ohm, for video it's 75Ohm. It's about the cables, not connectors.

Comment: @LeeSugden - 2 cores in a coax? Nope. Coax has a single core with a shield. There are specialty cables such as shielded twisted pair, but "composite video" usually means a single signal - it is composite due to the combining of video and sync, as in broadcast video.

Answer (score 2):

By a "composite video connection" I assume you mean an RCA connector such as you see on the back of a TV. In that case you need a simple "BNC female to RCA male" adapter, which looks like [image]

You can find these at places like Radio Shack, or at lots of places on the net.

ETA: In comment, a preference for direct connections due to reliability issues was expressed. The answer to that is simple - yes, such connectors are readily found. RCA connectors are widely used for home video/RF inputs, and something like [image: this] are readily available. Search on "RCA connector RG59" as a starting point.

END EDIT

Comment: Even at Amazon - https://www.amazon.com/RiteAV-BNC-Female-Male-Adapter/dp/B000V1O1L2/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1499284139&sr=8-4&keywords=BNC+female+to+RCA+male

Comment: Yes that's the one, the thing is I have tried these connectors time and time again they all fail eventually or cause interference with all my other camera equipment. Circuit board side I was wondering if I could solder a rca cable to it in place of the current BNC cable or would this not be possible?

Comment: @LeeSugden - See edit.

Comment: @LeeSugden - you are unlikely to achieve a better result during the first several attempts at replacing the connector than using a *quality* adapter.  If you do decide to replace the connector, spend some time studying the difference between connectors meant to be *crimped* vs those meant to be *soldered*.